# Angular - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on binding

Tags: angular, typescript, ngonchanges

I have one `<input>` field and one component which have a common model binded. I'm using `ngOnChanges()` in the component to check the value of that input, and also I'm changing the model binded to that input somewhere in this component.

Let say we binded `date` variable to the `<input>` and the component. The error occurs in that situation:

```
input field changed (also date changed) 
--> ngOnChanges 
--> new value of date doesn't fit requirements 
--> change the date to something else
--> <input> emits the new date
--> ngOnChanges() triggered again
--> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
```

Here are parts of my code:

`app.component.html`:

```
...
<input [(ngModel)]="date">
<app-date-picker [date]="date" (dateUpdated)="setDate($event)"></app-date-picker>
...
```

`app.component.ts`:

```
setDate(newDate: Date): void {
  this.date = newDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
}
```

`date-picker.component.ts`:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.date) ... // Do some checks
    if (invalidDate) {
       ...
       this.select(newDay);
    }
  }

  select(d: number): void {
    this.selectedYear = this.year;
    this.selectedMonth = this.month;
    this.selectedDay = this.day = d;
    this.dateUpdated.emit(new Date(this.year, this.month, this.day + 1));
  }
```

Comment: [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains this behavior in great details

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the date with a timeout:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if (changes.date) ... // Do some checks
  if (invalidDate) {
     ...
     setTimeout(() => { select(newDay); }, 50);
  }
}
```